# I wish to know how a function signature is validated

Tags: c++, function

I currently believe it is the compiler or the return type that does this but I'm not sure I just need a clarification

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: This question is not clear. To those closing: downvote rather than close.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "validated?"  I'm honestly not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @Pubby: Why would I do that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're the mod, you tell me!

Answer (score 3):

A function signature is matched first by it's name, then by it's arguments.  Never by it's return type.  For example if you have two methods called `Add` one taking two `int` values and returning a `int` and one taking two `string` values and returning a `string`, and you called it passing `int`s it wouldn't matter what you were setting it to the int version would be called.

Where this can get you in a bit of trouble is when you try method overloading with different numeric values.  the compiler will try and help you (if you call a method expecting ints but pass a short it will try and figure out what you are trying to do).

Comment: Yeah, I tripped over that method overloading compiler trying to help you thing in C#.  Unfortunately I never really identified a wholly satisfactory solution to the problem.